# Change of variable formula for density function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, jacobian

We all are aware of the change of variable formula whereby if $$[A,  B] = g(X, Y) $$ and $g$ are invertible,  then the joint density function of $A$, $B$ is given by
$$f_{ab} (A, B) =\frac1{|J|} f_{XY} (g^{-1}(a, b) ),$$  where $J$ is the Jacobian.

However,  if the joint distribution of $X, Y$ is not known but only the conditional distribution  of $X$ given $Y$ is known,  can we find the joint distribution of $A, B$ given $Y$.